# Is $n$ free in this formula?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, formal-languages

I have the following related questions:

$(1)$ Assume that the function symbol "function" has been defined. Is the following sentence $$\forall x_1,...,x_n (x_1,...,x_n \in \mathbb{R} \implies \exists f (function(f)\wedge \forall i \in\{1,...,n\}:f(i)=x_i))$$ a well formed formula and is "$n$" free in this formula? If so, how can I refer to $n$ within this formula by writing down the set $\{1,...,n\}$ and if not, how can I fix $n$ not being free?

$(2)$ Can I even write something like "(...) $f(i)=x_i$" above? Doesn't this assume that the variables behave like a function symbol, so I can "plug in" $i$? Does that mean I would have to write something like $$\forall x_1,...,x_n(x_1,...x_n \in \mathbb{R} \implies \exists f (function(f)\wedge f(1)=x_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge f(n)=x_n))?$$ This would include even more "..." notation, is there a way to write this formally?

$(3)$ In formal languages the "..." notation is not allowed, is there another way to write $\forall x_1,...,x_n$ there that is more formal? For sets one has $\bigcup$ and for sums one has $\sum$, which one could index over and which gets rid of "..." notations. Is there something similar for quantifiers?

Comment: No the formula is not a first order formula. Quantifiers cannot range over index of variables.

Comment: The reason is exactly that underlying point 3 above: "dots" are not allowed: a formula is made with "predicates" having a fixed number of arguments.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks, but if that is the case, how can I express such sentences? Is there another way in first order logic? I thought that when one writes "Let $x_1,...,x_n$" be real numbers that this is the first step in the universal generalization of $\forall x_1,...,x_n \in \mathbb{R}$. But if $\forall x_1,...,x_n$ is not expressible, this can't be the case.

Comment: For any fixed, finite $n$, this can be expressed as a first-order formula, by explicitly filling in the $\dots$ (the length of the formula increases with $n$), but with unspecified or variable $n$, it's not a first-order formula.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks! One often reads something like "Let $x_1,...,x_n$ be real numbers, which I thought is the first step of a proof of a statement which involves $\forall x_1,...,x_n$. As this does not seem to be expressible in FOL, what is the justification for writing the let statement above? And what do you mean with fixed $n$? Can one write something like $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \forall x_1,...,x_n(...)$?

Comment: In a sense you are mixing formally specified formulas of language with partially formal specifications written in meta-language  Dots are in the meta-language as well as numbers.